# Java Dateformat -- Can I compare input to certain formats and parse the input based on the format that it is matched to?

Tags: java, date, date-format

For example:

A user can enter 01/23/1983 or 1/23/1983

How would I use DateFormat to write up two different kinds of formats like (MM/DD/YYYY) and (M/DD/YYYY) and compare them to the actual date to see which one matches the date so I could parse it successfully?

Comment: First you should test it out by creating a SimpleDateFormat object with the format String you've got posted, and try to parse both test Strings. You may be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Though make the year's y's and day's d's lower case: `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.  The SimpleDateFormat class's API will tell you why this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Johan posted an incorrect solution, I feel obliged to post the correct one. `"MM/dd/yyyy"` will format both of your test Strings:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] tests = {"01/23/1983", "1/23/1983", "1/3/1983"};

      String formatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";

      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);

      for (String test : tests) {
         Date date = null;
         try {
            date = sdf.parse(test);
         } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         System.out.println(date);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common solution when dealing with multiple input formats is to try a series of expected formats in a loop until one succeeds, or all fails. E.g.,

```
public Date parseDate(List<DateFormat> formats, String text) {
    for(DateFormat fmt : formats) {
        try {
          return fmt.parse(inputDate);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {}
    }
    return null;
}

List<DateFormat> formats = Arrays.asList(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
Date d1 = parseDate(formats, "01/23/1983");
Date d2 = parseDate(formats, "1/23/1983");
```

Comment: No need and it's incorrect. Please see my comment to the original post. What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Ah, you've edited the dd's and the yyyy's now to lower case, but you still have unnecessary redundancy. Again, why do you feel the need to use an array list of SimpleDateFormat when only one is needed?

Comment: @Eels, ty you're right, it is redundant in this particular case; but nevertheless a common approach when dealing with multiple formats.